# Class methods self call best practice

Tags: c++, class, structure

Consider these following two C++ examples (even if language does not matter).

---

First, the `Foo` class, which call its own methods like `getSize()`, `isPosValid()`, `getElement()`.

```
class Foo {
private:
    std::vector<int> elements_ { };

public:
    size_t getSize() const {
        return elements_.size();
    }

    bool isPosValid(const size_t pos) const {
        return pos < getSize();
    }

    int getElement(const size_t pos) const {
        if (!isPosValid(pos)) {
            return 0;
        }

        return elements_[pos];
    }

    // Here we could use elements_.back(), but this is just for the example.
    int getLastElement() const {
        if (getSize() == 0u) {
            return 0;
        }

        return getElement(getSize() - 1u);
    }

    bool operator==(const Foo& rhs) const {
        return getSize() == rhs.getSize();
    }

    bool operator!=(const Foo& rhs) const {
        return !(*this == rhs);
        // OR maybe : return !operator==(rhs);
    }
}
```

---

Then, the `Bar` class, which don't call his own methods, but has kind of code duplicate.

```
class Bar {
private:
    std::vector<int> elements_ { };

public:
    size_t getSize() const {
        return elements_.size();
    }

    bool isPosValid(const size_t pos) const {
        return pos < elements_.size();
    }

    int getElement(const size_t pos) const {
        if (pos >= elements_.size()) {
            return 0;
        }

        return elements_[pos];
    }

    // Here we could use this->elements_.back(), but this is just for the example.
    int getLastElement() const {
        if (elements_.size() == 0u) {
            return 0;
        }

        return elements_[elements_.size() - 1u];
    }

    bool operator==(const Bar& rhs) const {
        return elements_.size() == rhs.elements_.size();
    }

    bool operator!=(const Bar& rhs) const {
        return elements_.size() != rhs.elements_.size();
    }
}
```

---

As you can see, `Foo` and `Bar` have different architectures.

Theses examples are very basic, but we can start to see some issues with both of them.

For `Foo`, `getElement()` verify the position, so if we call it when we already made the verification (like in `getLastElement()`), then it is done twice.

And for `Bar`, there is a lot of "code duplication", and if we want to modify how an element is accessed we have to do it in all methods that does the access. (Instead of just modifying the `getElement()` in the `Foo` example).

---

**Which design is best maintainable and readable. Is there a way to fix this design issue, without mixing both styles and keeping consistent?**

And kind of off topic question, is it better in C++ call operators inside a class like this `operator=(XXX)` or like this `*this = XXX;` (like in the `Foo::operator!=` example) ?

---

*EDIT: Removed `this->` qualifiers as suggested in comment.*

Comment: Are you sure you can't narrow this down to a more understandable [mcve]? Especially if this is a language agnostic question. Also, this looks like it's primarily opinion based.

Comment: I was thinking that code speak by itself. Could me more understandable than reading big text that explain it. And here i think there is a best way to go, i would like advices from people that know to to structure their code in order to prevent this kind of issue.

Comment: I would skip all the unnecessary `this->` which really clutters the code. It's pretty obvious that the class has an `elements_` member so you don't have to point that out in every single function. If you somehow were to access a non-member somewhere you better make *that* part stand out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the first one is a better design.  You always want to factor out common code (like the size checking) and reuse it in your class.  Your example is trivial but in the real world the check may be more than just looking at the size and you would want to put the common logic in one place.  That's just good software design.

For the logical operators, you always want to define != in terms of == for the same reason.  Similarly for other logical operators.

Also, use the more natural equality expression.  Using the operator=() function is much less readable.  Even for an experienced C++ programmer in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you for the good and clear reponse (excpecially for the operators). But when you say to factor out common code, how could it be done ? For exemple, if elements are replaced by a vector of tuple, and `getElement()` returns the first tuple value. The size verification is still done in this method. But if another method also has to access element first tuple value, and has already done size checking, should it call `getElement` or get it from the class member ?

Comment: You only want to do the size check once.  After you define all of the functions a user of your class will need, you can determine how best to factor out common code.  Due to the size check, you may want to access elements through a common function that does the size check.

Answer (score 0):

It is an **aspect of design**, which are you using and to continuesly use it. I personally prefer the `*this = XXX`, but when `ThisClass& operator =(OtherClass o)` does nothing other than assigning to a member of type`OtherClass` to the new value `o`, I just access the member directly inside another operator-/member-functions. However I implement `operator ==(..)` and `operator !=(..)` seperately (which is naively much faster), or I use a macro which automaticly implements `operator !=()` while `operator ==()` is implemented already by me (However it would be more elegant if C++ had an `int operator =?=(ThisClass)` which works like strcmp and returns -1 if lesser, 0 if equal or 1 if greater, and which automaticly defines the other classic comparison operators).

```
#define impl_operator_neq \
        template<typename T>
    bool operator(T other) { return !(*this == other);
```

### Edit

However I saw some naive code (which was wrong), that implemented the equality-operators like this:

```
bool operator ==(Account const& o) {
    return !(*this != o); // the person also tried return *this == o;
};

// ...

bool operator !=(Account const& o) {
    return !(*this == o);
};
```

The first one originally was like the following and later changed to that ridiculous code:

```
bool operator ==(Account const& o) {
    return !(strcmp(this->name, o.name));
};
```

So in this code it may be better to use `operator xy(..)` to indicate that it is calling another operator in the current class. However while operators are only syntactic sugar for calling a function, they can be virtual and overloaded in classes, so calling the so called super-function is only possible via casting or writing `this->BaseClass::operator!=(other)`.